# Define a variable in js with imported text

Tags: javascript

My js function use the variable "**categorylink**" for making some hyperlinks and it works well

```
$(function () {
    var chart1;
    var categoryLinks = {
    'Career prospects':'http://localhost/Landa/DirectManagers/501-NitzanHarLavan/Dim01.html',
    'Compensation':'http://localhost/Landa/DirectManagers/501-NitzanHarLavan/Dim02.html',
    };

    $.get('graphdata/DIMAVGOTHERSforMgrs.txt?x='+microtime(), function(json){
    obj = eval('({'+json+'})');     
    var $container = $('#container');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new  Highcharts.Chart(obj)
    });
  });
 });`
```

I want the **var categoryLinks = {.....};** part of the code to be imported from a text file. I have used

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', 'foo.txt');
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(client.responseText);
    }
    client.send();
```

with foo.txt containing the **var categoryLinks = {.....};** part of the code but it doesn't work

Please help

Comment: Rename `foo.txt` to `foo.js` and add `<script src="foo.js"></script>` to your HTML. No need to use Ajax to load a JavaScript file.

Comment: if you want json with jQuery use $.getJSON http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/